# Embedded Pig in python

Tags: python, apache-pig

While importing the module I am getting the below error:

```
from org.apache.pig.scripting import *
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named org.apache.pig.scripting
```

I am using Python version 2.6.6, jython 2.5.3 and pig 0.11.1.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried searching for the module `org.apache.pig.scripting` in your favorite search engine? What did that turn up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute like this:

```
pig -embedded jython myjob.py
```

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-4353